# Can qgraphicsscene be conveted to a pixmap?

Tags: qgraphicsscene

I want to convert a `QGraphicsScene` to a pixmap, so I can add it to a listwidget as a `QGraphicsPixmapItem`. I wonder is it possible?
In another word,  what I want to get is just like a `thumb` of a `QGraphicsScene`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but not directly.

You can convert a `QGraphicsView` into a pixmap, using the static function `QPixmap::grabWidget()`. Create a graphics view, attach your scene to the view, and then convert the widget.